# Workflow to "Check Out" List Items - Help Needed on "Cancel" and "View" Modes

Tags: workflow, infopath, custom-list, infopath-rules

Long time lurker, first time poster!

I have a SharePoint 2010 list that will be used to manage Personnel.  When an employee has been with the team for 1 week, an email goes out to 3 different administrators who each have different tasks.  Since they are all fields in the same list, there is a conflict if the list item is being edited by multiple users at once.  To prevent one user from having to refresh the page and lose all of his/her changes, I wanted to implement a "check out" workflow with InfoPath rules.

Basically on Form Load, the current User gets assigned to a "Check in/check out" field.  If there is a value in this field, subsequent users get an error message *prior to entering their data*.  Once the current user hits "Submit," the form resets to an "unlocked" (checked in) status.

There are two problems:

1. The item gets checked out to the initial user even if he/she opens in "View" mode instead of "Edit."  Can I use Form Load rules to only run if opened in "Edit" mode?
2. The item does not get checked in if the user does not hit "Submit."  If the user decides to cancel changes, the item should be checked in.  Is there a Form Close command in InfoPath?  If not, could I replicate this somehow via Workflow?

Any help with rectifying these issues would be much appreciated!

Thanks,
Jared